# ASAN: heap-use-after-free when flattening a binary tree to a linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, stack, binary-tree

This is a Leetcode question, Flatten Binary Tree to Linked List.

My solution is very straightforward. For a node `root`, push `root->right` onto a stack. Set the `root->left` to the `root->right` and set `root->left` to NULL.

I get a runtime error:

> AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000108 at pc
>   0x00000046bf70 bp 0x7ffc5d6c5f70 sp 0x7ffc5d6c5f68

What is causing the error?

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void flat_tree(TreeNode* pre, TreeNode* root, stack<TreeNode*>& s){ 
        if(root == NULL){
            if(s.empty()) return;
            else{
                TreeNode* newroot = s.top();  
                s.pop();
                pre->right = newroot;
                flat_tree(pre, newroot,s);
            }
        }else{
            if(root->left == NULL) {
                flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
            }else if(root->right == NULL){
                root->right = root->left;
                flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
            }else{
                TreeNode* right = root->right;
                root->right = root->left;
                s.push(right);
                flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
            }
        }
    }   

    void flatten(TreeNode* root) {
        stack<TreeNode*> s;
        flat_tree(NULL ,root,s);  
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very close. Left node pointers need to be nulled out after their child is moved over to the right side of the root, preventing the double free heap corruption which occurs when the test suite follows two pointers to the same memory location.

Here's the working code:

```
void flat_tree(TreeNode* pre, TreeNode* root, stack<TreeNode*>& s){ 
    if(root == NULL){
        if(s.empty()) return;
        else{
            TreeNode* newroot = s.top();  
            s.pop();
            pre->right = newroot;
            flat_tree(pre, newroot,s);
        }
    }else{
        if(root->left == NULL) {
            flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
        }else if(root->right == NULL){
            root->right = root->left;
            root->left = NULL; /* set the left pointer to null */
            flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
        }else{
            TreeNode* right = root->right;
            root->right = root->left;
            root->left = NULL; /* do the same here */
            s.push(right);
            flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
        }
    }
}
```

I also recommend reorganizing branches to avoid duplicated logic:

```
void flat_tree(TreeNode* pre, TreeNode* root, stack<TreeNode*>& s) { 
    if (root) { 
        if (root->right) {
            s.push(root->right);
        }

        root->right = root->left;
        root->left = NULL;
        flat_tree(root, root->right, s); 
    }
    else if (!s.empty()) {
        pre->right = s.top();
        s.pop();
        flat_tree(pre, pre->right, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. 
In the real project, is there a method that can be used to quickly tell us where the issue is?

Comment: No problem. If by "in the real project", you mean on the LC interface, all you get is the ASAN output. But then again ASAN is as good a tool for detecting these sort of problems as I can think of and the error message is pretty explicit in this case. Of course, coding in a higher-level language solves the problem by avoiding memory issues completely and gives stack traces, so you can always trade efficiency for easier coding and debugging.